# How to call a function in cypress from separate file?

Tags: cypress

Im calling this funcion in many tests. How can i put that in commands.js file and call it where needed

Comment: please include the code to the post. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Cypress guide. Cypress recommendation is to use commands.js

```
Documentation link :
[https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax][1]
```

You can add CategoryNumber() like this.  Go to Support Folder. You will see  Command.js

```
Cypress.Command.add('CategoryNumber, ()=> {

ACTUAL FUNCTION Code

}
```

How to call?

Go to test definition and call as `cy.CategoryNumber()`

```
example function :
```

> Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
>
> const domain = Cypress.env('BASE_DOMAIN')
>
> if (domain === '...') {
>       url = '...'   }
>
> if (options.something === 'else') {
>       url = '...'   }
>
> // originalFn is the existing `visit` command that you need to call 
>   // and it will receive whatever you pass in here.   //   // make sure
>   to add a return here!   return originalFn(url, options)
>
> })

Comment: this is index.js file : http://prntscr.com/p19hcs  ,   this is commands.js file  http://prntscr.com/p19hjg  , and this is test file in integration folder where i call the funcion http://prntscr.com/p19i08 , but im getting errors http://prntscr.com/p19i74

Comment: @YieldaToro - Please write function code in cypress.comand. You copied the entire function. That's wrong. I also updated answer based on that.